# Read HTML table after it has been modified by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to read through an HTML table that has been modified by JavaScript. I currently load a HTML table and when I click a certain cell, the words change in that cell using Javascript. I need to grab all the rows from that table that were clicked(the words changed from original HTML load) and when button is clicked a new page will open with just the 'clicked' rows information. ANY help would be great!! Thanks!!

Comment: Add relevant code when u ask a question....

Comment: I am working on attaching code.

Comment: I cannt get the code to upload but essentially what I am doing is Very simple. I have a HTML table with 5 columns and several rows. If you click in the 5th column cell then that particular cell will change text from "Add" to "Remove". I am using JavaScript to change that text. I now need to grab all the rows that say "Remove" in column 5 and create a new page with that information.

Comment: Any examples or code to do anything similar would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `data` attributes to the cells in the click handler:

```
$('td').on('click', function() { 
  $(this).attr('data-original-text', $(this).text());

  // Do the rest of your manipulation here
});
```

Clicked cells would then look like this:

```
<td data-original-text="Text before the click">...</td>
```

Gather up all that data in the button click event:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('td[data-original-text]').each() {
    // Serialize the values and send them off to the server
  });
});
```

---

**Or you could add a class, instead of a data attribute**

```
$('td').on('click', function() { 
  $(this).addClass('clicked');

  // Do the rest of your manipulation here
});
```

Get the rows and and send them to the server:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('tr:has(.clicked)').each(function() {
    // Serialize the values and send them off to the server
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually I don't think it would work since jQuery's data() function doesn't actually add the data value as an attribute to the DOM element:

**text**The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)**











But you can just add a class to the clicked cells instead of course.

Comment: You're right. Changed the first code bit to set the `attr` value, not the `data` value. JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/ePEkaw/1/edit

Comment: how would you go about adding a class for the clicked cells? Sorry Im very new to web development.

Comment: See the second example

Comment: This is what I have. 
 print "<td onclick='changeMe(this, ".$counter.")'>".$row['action']."</td>";

Comment: CHangeMe Function is this:

function changeMe(Cell, RowIndex)
{
 var Current = Cell.innerHTML;
 var NewValue;
 if (Current == "Add")
 {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('Day');
  var cardCount = document.getElementsByName('CardCount')
   
  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
          // do whatever you want with the checked radio
          Cell.innerHTML  = radios[i].value;